# 4 vertex shape faces

Tags: faces

Good day everybody.

I've been having troubles with a phantom face that appears when moving a vertex from a figure inside. I'm not sure how to explain it.

I have this face:
[image]

And by moving a vertex inside bends the face and keeps it triangle shaped. I get the following result:
[image]

In my head it should keep the limits within the edges, but it's not doing that, I wonder if this is normal and i'm chasing a ghost or is that I missed a step somewhere.

Sorry for the nuisance ^-^

Comment: Yes it should keep the limits within the edges. Can you upload your .blend file? (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Sure, here is the file:   [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2277" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2277/)

Comment: It shouldn't keep the limits of the edges in this case. There isn't enough geometry for that, because you create non-planar face by moving vertex like that, so it splits that face to 2 triangles. Try to avoid creating such geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Select the face that is not behaving properly. Press 'x' and choose 'Only Faces'.
And fill it again with selecting two edges and press 'f'.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just triangulate the face (ctrl+t) faces appear like that in blender it's just the way it is.. You can pres "F" afterwards but i suggest you to use triangles.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem came from the face but problably because your quad is convex so blender can't display it correctly. you can slit the face into two triangle. Select two vertices and press 'j'. 
Like that:[image]